# how to make a field requried when the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jsp

hello i am new to jsp and javascript, and i would like to a make a field required when the checkbox is checked,

```
            <tr>
            <th class="clsTableHeaderLeft">InterCompany</th>
            <td class="clsDisplayText"> 
<%              if (!tHideField.equals("")){
                    out.println(tRecord.get(idxInterComFlag).toString());
                }

%>          
                <input type="checkbox" class="clsInputText" <%=tHideField%> name="txtInterComFlag"  onchange="chgStatus(txtStatus);" size="25" maxlength="20" 

                <%=tRecord.get(idxInterComFlag).toString().equals("Y")?" checked":""%>
                />

            </td>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
            <th class="clsTableHeaderLeft">Entity Code</th>
            <td class="clsDisplayText">
<%              if (!tHideField.equals("")){
                    out.println(tRecord.get(idxInterComCode).toString());
                }

%>          


                <input type="text" class="clsInputText" <%=tHideField%> name="txtInterComCode"  size="25" maxlength="20" />


            </td>
        </tr>
```

also the checkbox value is 'on' when checked , how can I make it to Y or N? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same requirement, so i Choose to follow this flow:

- Create an onclick function at check box
- Get element ID of the html input element that needs to be changed
- create new html input element as required and replace it using Java script.

Here is my sample Code:

```js
function fxctco() {
 
 var newHTML="<input type='number' name='fctc'  required/>";
 document.getElementById("ctc").innerHTML = newHTML;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><TD ><input type="radio" name="fx"value="YES" onClick="fxctco()"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="fx"value="NO" checked> No</TD></tr>
 <tr><TD  id="ctc"> <INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="fctc"   /></TD></tr>
<tr>
<TD  align="center"><INPUT TYPE="submit" class="button" VALUE="submit"></TD>

</tr> </table>
```

Comment: would you mind share some of the code here? as I new to these language and seems many different way to write it. thanks so much

Comment: is it somthing like that? function validateForm() {
 
 var newHTML="<input type='number' name='txtInterComCode'  required/>";
 document.getElementById(tRecord.get(idxInterComCode)).innerHTML = newHTML;
}                                                                                                                
 <input type="checkbox" class="clsInputText" <%=tHideField%> name="txtInterComFlag"  onchange="chgStatus(txtStatus);" size="25" maxlength="20" 
    checked="checked" onClick= "validateForm()"
    />

Comment: it is really hard to read your code, Please follow due procedure while pasting code in comments.